# Connecting my desktop to anything other than directly to my modem/router (wired) brings down my entire internet connection

Tags: networking, windows-8

A week and a half ago, I started having an odd problem: with my main desktop connected to my gigabit switch, my internet connection would go dead, not just for my desktop, but for all of my devices.  My first instinct was that it was my actual internet connection, and so I had my ISP replace my modem.  That didn't solve the problem, but it did reveal that it was my computer to blame.  Trying different things, I found out that plugging my computer into the modem allowed me to maintain my internet connection.  This wasn't ideal, since my modem only supports 100 Mb/s connections, and all my other wired devices of note have gigabit ethernet, but with a new motherboard on order, this would be enough.

I now have that new motherboard up and running, but still have the same issue.  Obviously it wasn't the NIC in the old motherboard as I had suspected.  I've done virus scans and had zero detections.  The only program that was installed around the time I first noticed the issue was Mozilla Maintenance Service, and the Windows updates that were installed around that time were related to [KB2964358](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2964358) and [KB2959977](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2959977).  The former update is an IE fix, while the latter is a fix to a previous update about scanning Windows Server Update Services servers, which doesn't apply to me at home.  I've uninstalled this update and have not seen a difference.

In addition to the above, I've tried using different ethernet cables, connecting through my basic gigabit switch, connecting through my access point/switch (which connects through my first switch), and disabling all incoming and outgoing firewall rules (although I didn't delete any of them).

What could be causing this odd issue, and poison the well for all my other devices?

Comment: This reminds me of a gotcha that happened a long time ago. I installed a network card in an old XP PC. XP saw the card, installed drivers and everything appeared to work. Then gremlins came and went randomly on all network PCs (unable to print, no internet, etc). Eventually I discovered that the network card's Mac address was set to all 0's. I had to run the card's own installer to give it a proper Mac address. After that everything was OK. Moral of the story: use IPCONFIG /ALL to ensure everything is set correctly.

Comment: @hdhondt I don't see anything suspicious, but [here's the output from ipconfig.](http://pastebin.com/bx2bVDaL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a few things that conspired against me.  The NIC on my old motherboard may very well be (nearly) dead, I may confirm that later if I decide to put it to use in a secondary machine.  However, in attempting to fix the problem before receiving my new motherboard (perhaps when the ISP tech was here), I swapped out a working cable with one that I had lying around, but this other cable was only meant for use with older equipment, and only has 4 conductors.  This obviously caused problems with the switch, but the router was able to cope with it.  It probably also caused the NIC to enter a weird state where it wouldn't right itself when I plugged in a different (CAT5 or CAT5e) cable.

The offending cable has been destroyed.